# Chaincall for each element in list

Tags: list, function, kotlin, collections

Is exist elegant way to call function on every element in list to tie with next till the end?

For example I have:

```
val list = listOf(1,5,3,4)
fun Int.foo(next: Int) = //some logic
```

I want to generate this expression:

```
val result = 1.foo(5).foo(3).foo(4)
```

Comment: What is the 'some logic' doing? This might be important to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: It modifies both numbers and returns a new one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such operation is called **reducing** or **folding** a collection and is done using [reduce()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/reduce.html):

```kotlin
list.reduce(Int::foo)
```

For example:

```kotlin
1.plus(5).plus(3).plus(4) // 13
listOf(1, 5, 3, 4).reduce(Int::plus) // 13
```

Comment: (I think the terminology comes from the world of Functional Programming, which is why it may not be familiar to everyone.)